# Mailchimp python wrapper gives error - no session

Tags: python, django, session, mailchimp

I'm trying to implement the mailchimp python API in a django project similar, following their example on github. I was trying to make a connection in a class based view however when I load up the view I get the notice

`Attribute Error at\
'module' object has no attribute 'session'`

It's set up exactly like their example and the error occurs where I define

`m = get_mailchimp_api()`

I opened up the mailchimp.py file in my site packages after following the traceback and saw the following:

```
import requests

class Mailchimp(object):
    root = 'https://api.mailchimp.com/2.0/'
    def __init__(self, apikey=None, debug=False):
        '''Initialize the API client

        Args:
           apikey (str|None): provide your MailChimp API key.  If this is left as None, we will attempt to get the API key from the following locations::
               - MAILCHIMP_APIKEY in the environment vars
               - ~/.mailchimp.key for the user executing the script
               - /etc/mailchimp.key
           debug (bool): set to True to log all the request and response information to the "mailchimp" logger at the INFO level.  When set to false, it will log at the DEBUG level.  By default it will write log entries to STDERR
       '''

        self.session = requests.session()
```

The traceback ends at the `self.session = requests.session()` line.

This is my view where I am trying to call Mailchimp

```
from app.utils import get_mailchimp_api
import mailchimp
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    # print requests -- this is undefined
    m = get_mailchimp_api()
```

Is it because the CBV doesn't have a request parameter? In the github example they show the connection being made in a function based view where the function takes a requests. If that's the case, how can I pass the response into the CBV? This is the exact example Mailchimp gives on github:

```
def index(request):
   try:
      m = get_mailchimp_api()
      lists = m.lists.list()
   except mailchimp.Error, e:
      messages.error(request, 'An error occurred: %s - %s' % (e.__class__, e))
      return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) doesn't have a `session()` method...but id *does* have a `Session()` object.

Sounds like a bug in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Requests aliases [Session() with session()](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L682), so that's probably not the issue. It almost sounds like there's something up either with your `get_mailchimp_api()` method or something is weird with the imports. Other stackoverflow questions about similar error messages seem to come from mutual imports, typos, or other such things.

Presumably your `app.utils` module is importing `mailchimp` already, [like MailChimp's does](https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-python-examples/blob/master/django/mcapi_python_example/utils.py)? If not, I'd try that. If so, maybe remove your `import mailchimp` from this file.